# Execute mplayer bash command using python 2.7

Tags: python, mplayer

How do I execute the following linux command line command using Python

> ```
> mplayer -identify -frames 0 -vo null -nosound metallica.mp4 2>&1 | awk -F= '/LENGTH/{print $2}'
> ```

I tried

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["mplayer","-identify","-frames","0","-vo","null","-nosound","test1.mp4","2>&1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk","-F","'/LENGTH/{print $2}'"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2.communicate()
```

I am getting the following error for the above

> mplayer: could not connect to socket mplayer: No such file or
>   directory Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use
>   your remote control.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

cmdline = "mplayer -identify -frames 0 -vo null -nosound metallica.mp4 2>&1 | awk -F= '/LENGTH/{print $2}'"
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p1.communicate())
```